# How to insert a ListView in a Column, all nested in a SingleChildScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm writing a MacOS application, using Flutter, that has to show a lot of text data to the user.

I decided to implement a vertical ListView in a Column like this:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 16.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                height: 25,
                child: Row(children: [
                  Text("someText"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Text("someText"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Text("someText"),
                  ...  
                ]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
);
```

So far so good.

But from now on, I need to wrap all that code in a horizontal SingleChildScrollView so that the user can scroll the entire page in horizontal way too.

My attempt:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, left: 16.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ...
            ],
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
                height: 25,
                child: Row(children: [
                  Text("someText"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Text("someText"),
                  const SizedBox(width: 16),
                  Text("someText"),
                  ...  
                ]),
              );
            },
            itemCount: 100,
          ),
        ),
      ],
   )
);
```

But I get the following error:

> Vertical viewport was given unbounded width.
>
> Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a vertical shrinkwrapping viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand.

I don't know how to fix that problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us about the parent widget of `Column`?

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Yes of course. The Column is in a ChangeNotifierProvider, that is in a Scaffold

Comment: I am also awaiting for answer..I had the same and when could not get solution i used pageView...

Comment: The main issue here having infinite constraints on ListView, can be use SingleChildScrollView. I dont think this will be optimal solution. using Slivers or NestedScrollView might be better option for you.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?